# Passing Argument 1 makes integer from pointer without a cast warning

Tags: c

I am using CodeBlocks and learning C. I created this simple script as a point for learning functions. I am not understanding the error I am getting though as everything matches up in my eyes.

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SetPerson(char a, int b);

int main () {

    char name[50];
    int number[6];

    printf("Enter Name: ");
    scanf("%49s", name);

    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%5d", number);

    SetPerson(name, number);

    return(0);
} 

void SetPerson(char a, int b) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", a);
    printf("Number: %d", b);
}
```

In the compiler I am getting these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in remove (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|17|warning: passing argument 1 of 'SetPerson' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|4|note: expected 'char' but argument is of type 'char *'|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|17|warning: passing argument 2 of 'SetPerson' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|4|note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c||In function 'SetPerson':|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|23|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 3 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

EDIT:

I changed as recommend:

```
SetPerson(char *a, int b);
```

And now I am at these errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in remove (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|17|warning: passing argument 2 of 'SetPerson' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|
C:\Users\e\Desktop\c programs\remove\main.c|4|note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'int *'|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: `name` is not a `char`. It's a pointer to a `char` (since it's an array of `char), which is a `char *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is an array of characters, but the first argument to `SetPerson` is a single character. Change `SetPerson` to

```
void SetPerson(char* a, int b) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", a);
    printf("Number: %d", b);
}
```

Note that in C, arrays and pointers are basically interchangeable.

**Edit** (after question was modified)

You're basically doing the same thing in reverse with the number. You have an array of ints (basically `int*` which you're passing to a `int` argument.

Drop the array portion of the declaration for `number`; you're not telling the compiler to allocate a 6-digit (in base 10) number, you're telling it to allocate 6 32-bit (probably; `int` is generally 32-bit these days, but may not be) numbers.

Then you'll need to change the arguments to scanf to pass a *pointer* to `number` instead of the actual number; use the address-of operator (`&`) for that:

```
scanf("%d", &number);
```

Comment: I see the error in my code now. The pointer should point to the start of the array. I have edited and still have a error that I am not sure about.

Comment: @BrianJarcus learn from the previous error. it's exactly the same error. `number` is an array of `char`, so it's a `char *`. But in this case, `number` should not be an array of `int`. You've declared it as `int number[6]` which is an array of six `int` values. It should just be an `int`. Why did you make it an array?

Comment: I may have been confused as I was learning and thought that was the max limit of what I wanted it to hold. I have taken a further look into the variables and I was confused. This has helped me clarify how these variables operate.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an array for an integer if you just want to store a single integer? If you want to store five integers then you're doing it incorrectly. 
If you want to store all five integers, then apply a `for` or `while` loop for scanning each number:

```
int number[5];

for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
{
     scanf("%d", number[i]);
}
```

In your code, `scanf("%5d", number);` would just store any number up to five digits, not those 5 digits separately.

Now the thing left about passing those arrays to another functions. Here you have to pass the addresses of those arrays as `SetPerson(name, number);`, and in the formal arguments you have to define pointers for the respective variables such as

```
SetPerson( char *a, int *b )
```

Inside this function you're printing the string in a correct way, but not the integers (if you wanna print all the 5 integers in separately). For the condition I've written inside the parenthesis, you must apply a `while` or a `for` loop to print those integers separately.